# Draw axis text label in OpenGL for a Qt project

Tags: qt, opengl, text, drawing, rendering

I have an x, y, z axis in the lower left-hand corner to give the user an idea of orientation.  I want to label these axes with the appropriate x, y, and z labels.

I know that I don't want to use Glut to accomplish this since it's old and outdated, and was wondering if I could leverage QPainter to help label these axes.

NOTE: I've seen this, but found it too much: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/

Comment: So you already draw the lines? Could you please post this piece of code so we can suggest you something that fits into your existing code?

Comment: Not really relevant.  I just want to know how to draw text in OpenGL.  Then from there I will be able to apply it to my axes.

Comment: "How to draw text in OpenGL" is not very specific. Qt has a lot of wrapper stuff to operate with OpenGL, one of them is the QPainter on a QGLWidget. Are you drawing your scene on such a QGLWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QPainter to draw text on any paint device. A QGLWidget is such a paint device; QPainter will then use OpenGL to draw the text (or whatever you want to draw). Guessing you are using a QGLWidget to draw your scene, you can just put the QPainter stuff at the end of your paintEvent:

```
MyGLWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    // draw OpenGL scene
    // ...

    // draw labels:
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawText(..., ..., "X");
    p.drawText(..., ..., "Y");
    p.drawText(..., ..., "Z");
    p.end();
}
```

Also have a look at the [Qt OpenGL Overpainting Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/opengl-overpainting.html).

Comment: Good answer; however, I got ahead of myself :(

QPainter won't work since my code isn't inside a `QWidget`, therefore, I have no `paintEvent()` function.

Comment: @user869525 That's why I asked ;) On which object are you drawing your scene? If it is a QPaintDevice, you could just put the code anywhere and add substitute `QPainter p(this);` with `QPainter p; p.begin(this);`. But I never tried this, it may work or may not ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because (you said) you don't have access to QPainter for some reason, you need some kind of font rendering library for OpenGL. You could use [FTGL](http://homepages.paradise.net.nz/henryj/code/) or you can make your own renderer using [freetype 2](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/index.html). Starting with Qt version 4.8.1 it should be possible to access individual glyphs using [QRawFont](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qrawfont.html) (without having to directly deal with freetype), which can make implementing your own font rendering routines even easier.

If your object is QPaintDevice or QGLWidget, then use QPainter. It might be slower than traditional texture font, but it'll save you (from) another coding headache.